# Upgrade to 18.04 fails with Grub error

Tags: boot, grub2, upgrade, uefi, nvme

On 10 [HP Prodesk 600 G3](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c05365730) PCs with i5 3.4GHz CPUs, NVMe disks, and Ubuntu 17, I've been running Ubuntu 17 for an examination system. In order to upgrade Virtualbox, I had to upgrade 17 -> 18. Except, it didn't work. In the end, I always end up with an error telling that grub cannot been installed. I can install 17, without any problem, but I can't install anything on 17. Tried 19, and same thing, didn't install grub.

I have tried A LOT of suggested fixes here, but no go. It ends with not installing grub in the end of installing process. And yes, I have manually partitioned the disk, I have tried via Live-USB to install Ubuntu (UEFI) and manually install grub.  I have tried the Super Grub2, ends with same error. Firmware is updated, any hint concerning this very model would help a lot.

Peter

edit: I pretty much tried everything about this topic found here, nothing worked. I choose the simplest installation, erase the disk, and get:

The partition tables on the following devices are changed:
/dev/nvme0n1

The following partitions are going to be formated:
partition#1 of /dev/nvme01 as ESP
partition#2 of /dev/nvme01 as ext4

Files are being copied, and in the end it comes to:

"The 'grub-efi-amd64-signed' package failed to install into /target/. Without the GRUB boot loader, the installed system will not boot."

No matter what I try, it ends up like this. Except for Ubuntu 17 of course, then it is up and running in minutes...

I've partitioned manually, tried many alternatives, booted Legacy and UEFI, changed usb-memories, downloaded image several times, and now I'm out of ideas...

Edit: thought I'd try to install 17, went fine again, and install 18 alongside, maybe adding 18 to existing grub would fix it, but no. Same error...

Comment: It's very helpful for us to know exactly what you tried (including the specfici commands) and the exact error messages. Please click [edit] and update the question with that infor. Please don't use Add Comment; instead, use [edit].